# Unable to convert to x264 mkv

Tags: video, codecs, avconv, h264

I want to convert an `mp4` file to `mkv` with the video format as `x264` and audio as `libmp3lame`

1. Mediainfo for the file gives:

   ```
   General
   Complete name                            : file_in.mp4
   Format                                   : MPEG-4
   Format profile                           : Base Media
   Codec ID                                 : isom
   File size                                : 404 MiB
   Duration                                 : 41mn 4s
   Overall bit rate                         : 1 375 Kbps
   Writing application                      : Lavf56.1.0
   Video
   ID                                       : 1
   Format                                   : MPEG-4 Visual
   Format profile                           : Advanced Simple@L5
   Format settings, BVOP                    : Yes
   Format settings, QPel                    : No
   Format settings, GMC                     : No warppoints
   Format settings, Matrix                  : Default (H.263)
   Codec ID                                 : 20
   Duration                                 : 40mn 55s
   Bit rate                                 : 1 185 Kbps
   Width                                    : 576 pixels
   Height                                   : 432 pixels
   Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
   Frame rate mode                          : Constant
   Frame rate                               : 29.970 fps
   Color space                              : YUV
   Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
   Bit depth                                : 8 bits
   Scan type                                : Progressive
   Compression mode                         : Lossy
   Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.159
   Stream size                              : 347 MiB (86%)
   Writing library                          : XviD 1.3.0.dev55
   Audio
   ID                                       : 2
   Format                                   : AC-3
   Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
   Mode extension                           : CM (complete main)
   Format settings, Endianness              : Big
   Codec ID                                 : ac-3
   Duration                                 : 41mn 4s
   Bit rate mode                            : Constant
   Bit rate                                 : 192 Kbps
   Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
   Channel positions                        : Front: L R
   Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
   Bit depth                                : 16 bits
   Compression mode                         : Lossy
   Stream size                              : 56.4 MiB (14%)
   ```
2. `libx264-dev` and `libav-tools` are the latest versions.
3. I tried converting with the following command

   ```
   avconv -i file_in.mp4 -c:v libx264 -acodec libmp3lame file_out.mkv
   ```
4. Output of the avconv command was

   ```
   avconv version 11.2-6:11.2-1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
     built on Jan 18 2015 05:12:33 with gcc 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu2)
   [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xa1d4c0] multiple edit list entries, a/v desync might occur, patch welcome
       Last message repeated 1 times
   [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xa1d4c0] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached
   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file_in.mp4':
     Metadata:
       major_brand     : isom
       minor_version   : 512
       compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
       encoder         : Lavf56.1.0
     Duration: 00:41:04.99, start: 0.016000, bitrate: 1375 kb/s
       Stream #0.0(und): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1184 kb/s, 30k tbn (default)
       Stream #0.1(und): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
   Output #0, matroska, to 'file_out.mkv':
     Metadata:
       major_brand     : isom
       minor_version   : 512
       compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
       encoder         : Lavf56.1.0
       Stream #0.0(und): Audio: libmp3lame, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
       Metadata:
         encoder         : Lavc56.1.0 libmp3lame
   Stream mapping:
     Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (ac3 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
   size=     315kB time=19.75 bitrate= 130.8kbits/s
   .
   .
   .
   .
   size=   39227kB time=2464.97 bitrate= 130.4kbits/s    
   video:0kB audio:38516kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.845972%
   ```

Essentially only the audio is copied. How do I get the video+audio in `mkv` format?

Comment: You tagged this with `ffmpeg`, but it appears you did not test it (`avconv` is not equivalent to `ffmpeg`).

Comment: apologies - removed tag

Answer (score 1):

Your video is encoded as "MPEG4 Visual", this is another name for mp42.  Unfortunately, this video was encoded using software that was developed in a time where the MPEG4-2 standard was no yet implemented.

By the time it was ready for general use, other codecs had taken its place (namely x264 etc).

This means that support for this codec is rudimentary, and struggles at best.

That said, you can fix the file somewhat, into a format that ffmpeg will read properly.

The part that ffmpeg has difficulty with, is the `major_brand : isom` part of the metadata.

To get around this, we use another tool: [MP4Box](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/)

Then, once you have MP4Box installed, you run a command like this:

```
MP4Box -brand mp42 input.mp4
```

This should change the metadata to read `major_brand : mp42`

Once this has been completed, ffmpeg should recognize it, and be able to convert it properly.

Good luck! :)